# iPhone App: UIScrollView with horizontal scrolling embedded in UIScrollView with Vertical scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have UIScrollView (horizontal scroll) embedded in another main UIScrollView (Vertical scroll). However, I can only scroll the inner scrollview (the horizontal one). What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If height of horizontal scrollview is less than vertical scrollview then set horizontal scrollview contentsize height same as its original height which you have set in nib file.
For example, if your inner scrollview height is 200px then set its contentsize like this: innerScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000,200) and uncheck vertical scrolling option for this scroll view from nib file. Enable pagging for inner scrollview if required. Uncheck horizonal scrolling of you main scrollview too so that it will scroll vertically only.